# Auto/car loan or mortgage applications and consolidated hard pulls

Tags: loans, home-loan, auto-loan

I heard on the radio recently that if one applies for an automobile loan or a home mortgage, multiple loan applications show up as one hard pull on your credit report. Is there a time period where all the hard pulls are merged together? The radio said a short period of time, but that is vague. Does anyone know the specifics?

Comment: They won't appear merged together on your report. However, they may be taken as a merged pull in the FICO score calculations. It is kind of murky so it's merely an experiment.

Answer (score 1):

This phenomenon is called [rate shopping](http://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/2009/03/01/impact-on-credit-scores-of-inquiries-for-an-auto-loan/). It is very hard to tell the specifics as each model will have its own thresholds.

For example, for [FICO models](http://www.myfico.com/crediteducation/creditchecks/inquiries.aspx), they have a 30 days window period for mortgage, auto, and student loans. But in some circumstances they may consider any similar inquiries outside this window as well.

> In addition, the score looks on your credit report for mortgage,
>   auto, and student loan inquiries older than 30 days. If it finds some,
>   it counts those inquiries that fall in a typical shopping period as
>   just one inquiry when determining your score.

Whereas [Experian has a different take on this window](http://www.experian.com/credit-education/score-faqs.html). They do not have such pre-defined time period, but it is [mentioned as 14 days in some places](http://www.experian.com/blogs/ask-experian/2009/03/01/impact-on-credit-scores-of-inquiries-for-an-auto-loan/).

> Too many inquiries may have a negative impact on your credit score.
>   However, most recently developed credit scores recognize when a
>   consumer is shopping for the best rates and either ignore multiple
>   inquiries or count them as only one inquiry if they occur within a
>   specific period of time. In such cases, shopping around will have
>   little or no impact on a credit score.

So as you can see, every model has a different approach and it is hard to make a concrete rule out of this. But as a thumb rule, try to keep it within a month and you should be okay. Also mind that this luxury is not available for credit card inquiries but only for loan inquiries.